# Running through the Azure DevOps Fundamentals for beginners course, having trouble with the release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

So I'm currently trying to proceed through the release pipeline portion of an Azure DevOps Fundamentals for beginners course on Udemy, and the goal is to deploy the code for a small webapp game called "Flatris" for the purpose of showing how Azure works.

I've been following along with all the steps as per the course, but when I run the release pipeline build, it consistently fails with the message:

"Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a***.zip
Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job."

So far, I've double checked the function of the Web App resource provided through Azure, it's showing traffic when I try and run the pipelines, so it's not the problem(i think), I've double checked the repositories, and they seem to be functioning well(i think), I'm unsure about the artifacts and whether that may be the source of the problem, but theres not enough specificity in the error logs for me to accurately isolate where the problem is.

I don't know if anyone else has managed to get pat this problem, or if it's unique to me with something I'm doing, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What steps have you taken to troubleshoot the issue on your own?

Comment: I've tried creating new pipelines from scratch to see if it was some setup step I missed, reconnecting to Github and Azure repos to see if resetting the connections will do anything, editing the service name, re-authenticating the Azure subscription, run the pipeline through Azure and Node.js, run it through with different repos to see if it was something with the code that was updated and didn't jive with the current Azure setup(I think the course was last updated around April of this year, but most of it is older). I still keep getting the same error message, regardless of what I've tried.

Comment: Did you look at what the error message said and validate whether the package exists in the path specified? And if not, where it may have been placed?

Comment: Honestly I'm not that experienced in identifying files like that, I wouldn't know where to begin with finding a package folder or file without something more specific to go off of.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a***.zip
> Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job."

When we use release pipeline for our application, we have to specify the **artifacts** that make up the application. And the artifact is a deployable component of your application. It is typically produced through a Continuous Integration or a build pipeline. Azure Pipelines releases can deploy artifacts that are produced by a wide range of artifact sources such as Azure Pipelines build, Jenkins, or Team City.

According to the error message, it seems you are using the build pipeline as artifact resource in the release pipeline.

To resolve this issue, we need make sure we have use the [Publish build artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) task to publish the artifacts to the Azure Pipelines in the build pipeline.

Then select the above build pipeline when we select the artifact source type:

[image]

In this case, Azure release pipeline will download the artifact automatically when we execute the release pipeline, the artifact will be save in the default folder `D:\a\r1\a`. That will resolve your issue.

Comment: This is something I have tried on several different attempts, but when I try and input the build pipeline, a notification comes up just beneath the text box saying "No version is available for Newest Flatris Repo or the latest version has no artifacts to publish. Please check the source pipeline."

Is there some option that I need to select during the initial Build pipeline so that it produces artifacts?

Comment: @ZachGoyer, According to the error, obviously you do not have a build pipeline for Flatris Repo, or your pipeline does not generate any artifacts. Please make sure you have a pipeline for Flatris Repo and it generates the artifact. If you do not know how to this, please share the image about your build definition. https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/devopsserver/build/